# Snapping in classic view does not properly position the close button

Tags: windows-7

I'm using classic view on Windows 7. When I snap a window to the right, its close button ends up in the top right corner is a few pixels away from the edge of the screen. This is a lot more difficult to reach than the close button of a maximized window.

I would like it to behave similar to a maximized window.

[image: comparison]

Upper image actual behavior, lower image desired behavior (mouse cursor in toprightmost corner accesses the close button directly).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @Dave Could you explain this in more detail? I have no idea where to look :(

Comment: No, sorry, I had mis-read your question. I thought you could change V-ALIGN or H-ALIGN on your comnputer screen, sorry